# Does await statement in the callee function causes the caller function to continue executing?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
async function innerFunc() {
 await doThis();
 await doThisNext();
 return 5;
}

async function outerFunc() {
 innerFunc();
 return 10;
}
```

When 'await' statement inside innerFunc() is executed, innerFunc() is suspended right away and anything outside of innerFunc() goes on as usual (which in this case causes outerFunc() to return 10 and quit. Is that correct?

But then what happens to outerFunc() when innerFunc() is successfully done returning 5 since the former doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: `outerFunc` will return before `innerFunc` is done because you didn't await `innerFunc` in the `outerFunc`

Comment: but where exactly innerFunc returns to (since outerFunc doesn't exist anymore for innerFunc to return to?)

Comment: I don't understand your question. `outerFunc` will return the value `10` and `innerFunc` will return `5`...

Comment: Well, async/await is just syntactic sugar for `Promise`, which executes without blocking. The only way to make `Promise` "block" (effectively, but not actually) is to add a function that should be executed after the `Promise` finishes executing, or a callback. This is added with `.then`, or with `await`. Since you don't want for `innerFunc`, nothing happens to `outerFunc` when `innerFunc` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When `await` statement inside `innerFunc` is executed, `innerFunc()` is suspended right away and anything outside of `innerFunc()` goes on as usual.

Yes.

> But then what happens when `innerFunc()` is successfully done returning `5`?

The promise that was the result of the `innerFunc()` call is getting fulfilled with the `return` value `5`. Similarly, the promise would get rejected had the code in `innerFunc` thrown an exception.

> What happens to `outerFunc()` since the former doesn't exist anymore?

Nothing happens to it - as you say, it's gone, and has no relation to the promise. It should have `await`ed it.